# Get data from data folder?

Tags: jekyll

I need to get some data using a dynamic name from front matter:

```
{{ site.data.prd-[page.tag].title" }}
```

The above fails to get the string from the data folder and nothing is output.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do but how about make a dictionary type data in `_data` directory and search for a title that matches `page.tag` in desired pages?

#### _data.prd-tags.yml

For each item, we can access the key and value using index ([0]: key, [1]: value).

```
jekyll: "jekyll's title"
ruby: "ruby's title"
html: "html's title"
.
.
.
```

#### HTML fragment for searching and displaying a tag (if found)

Iterate over `site.data.prd-tags` and display title if an item that matches `page.tag` is found.

```
<div class="tag-title">
  {% for tag in site.data.prd-tags  %}
    {% if tag[0] == page.tag %}
      {{ tag[1] }}
    {% else %}
      Nothing found
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```